# Why can’t the Doctor’s companions understand babies and horses?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

The Doctor claimed to speak both horse and baby. The reason human companions can understand every language is because the TARDIS translates. So why can't anyone else understand babies and horses?

Comment: When you say “anyone else”, I assume you mean companions in the TARDIS. And if so, what makes you think they can’t?

Comment: Because the doctor has to interprate for amys baby to amy

Comment: My question is under the assumption the tardis does translate, but why only for the doctor

Comment: Gotcha, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Bluntly, there's no specific evidence that the Doctor *actually* speaks baby or horse, even if such as thing was possible. The claims he makes may be part of his own fantasies, [outright lies](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rule%20one) or (more likely) used as misdirection to keep the person he's speaking to off-balance.

Certainly when he claims in "[A Town Called Mercy](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-3.htm)" that he speak horse this is the first time in [many occasions](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Horse) where he's *ridden* horses, that he says that he can actually *speak* to them. The fact that he does so in front of a **bible-thumping preacher** is especially telling.

> **PREACHER:** *He's called Joshua. It's from the Bible. It means the Deliverer.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *No, he isn't. I speak horse. He's called Susan, and he wants you to respect his life choices.*

Comment: So you mean that Alfie Owens doesn't actually call himself "Stormageddon: Dark Lord of All"?

Comment: @Xantec - Alas, he may simply have been joking. Sorry. http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Baby_(language)

Comment: I think he's cold reading the baby.  Statistically likely that anyone likes be to called Stormageddon: Dark Lord of All